# View going back to centre when the next text field begins editing

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a view with 2 textfields in it and have created a custom UIView class that manages textfield positioning when it is in editing mode.

When the first textfield begins editing, the view positions itself correctly to avoid keyboard overlapping, but when i hit the next textfield while the first textfield is in editing mode (or type anything), the view goes back to centre

here is my code:-

```
    class ActiveKeyboardView: UIView {

    var distanceBetweenViewAndKeyboard : CGFloat = 10

    private var viewOriginalYPoint : CGFloat = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpKeyboardObserver()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setUpKeyboardObserver()
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    private func setUpKeyboardObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func handleKeyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else {return}

        viewOriginalYPoint = self.frame.origin.y
        let viewsBottomPoint = self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height
        let keyboardTop = keyboardFrame.origin.y

        if keyboardTop < viewsBottomPoint {
            self.frame.origin.y -= (abs(viewsBottomPoint-keyboardTop) + distanceBetweenViewAndKeyboard)
        }
    }

    @objc private func handleKeyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardAnimationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {return}

        UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardAnimationDuration) { [weak self] in
            self?.frame.origin.y = (self?.viewOriginalYPoint)!
        }
    }
}
```

here is the github [link](https://github.com/AbhinavKhandujaDev/ActiveKeyboardView)

Comment: you can use ActiveKeyboardView for make difference between keyboard and textfield or any other reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ActiveKeyboardView` Embed in `Scroll View` so it can be automatically scrolling in `ActiveKeyboardView` `Textfield` begins editing.

If you are using `ActiveKeyboardView` for make KeyBoard distance with Textfield you can use `CocoaPods` in your project.

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

and you can add line in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        return true
}
```

if you want to make specific distance between Keyboard and UITextfield than use line.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 50
```